# What is the "regex" to only detect "."

Tags: javascript, regex, p5.js

im building a calculator on javascript with p5.js"s library.
and i want to make the "."(coma) for the numbers

wut is the regex for "." only

i tried `/^[]\.[]*$/` `/^-?\d*[.]?\d*$/` but it still didnt detect it

```
  if(mouseX > 110 &&///.
     mouseX < 190 &&
     mouseY < 570 &&
     mouseY > 490)
  {
 if(/^[]\.[]*$/.test(numtext) == true){
 numtext = numtext.substr(0, numtext.length - 1);
 }else
  numtext = numtext + "."
  }
```

i expect after i put that code that it will delete the text.length when it detected 2 ."s

Comment: Are you only looking to match `.`? Nothing else? Do you have sample strings you do and don't want to match?

Comment: Can you add the input and the desired output ?

Comment: just use literal dot like this `\.`

Comment: I think regex is useless here, you can do `"15.00".indexOf(".")`. ref : [`str.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: it worked thanks. ```indexOf()``` is da bes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to R3step.

instead of using .'s regex, i used [str.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

here is the solved code if you want to see it

```
   if(numtext.indexOf(".") !== -1)
   {
   numtext = numtext;
   }else
   numtext = numtext + ".";
  }
```

Comment: why are you doing `numtext = numtext`?

Comment: i want nothing to change on "numtext"

Comment: Then you should invert your if statement to get rid of that line. As if you make no operations on a variable it will stay the same!